# Ruby on Rails Search Returns Everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search

Ok Guys I know I have had a lot of beginner questions the last few days as my first ROR app comes together (beta deadline this wednesday).  Everything is all good and well, except for one hiccup I just came across while testing my app.

The app is for a casino in order for them to process background checks.  I have an Applicant model and applicants have first_name last_name attributes.  I wanted to be able to search my index page of applicants, but whenever I type the name into the search the browser is returning a new page of all the applicants and not just the one I am looking for...

I have been scouring the internet all morning looking for a solution, but I have had no luck.

Here is my applicant model

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :social, :dob
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
validates :social, format: {with: /^(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}|XXX-XX-XXXX)$/i, :multiline => true, on: :create}

def self.search(search)
  if search
    @applicants = Applicant.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name    LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    @applicants = Applicant.all
  end
end
end
```

(sorry for the poor indents it looks better in my file)
My controller looks like this

```
       def index
       @applicants = Applicant.search(params[:search])
       end
```

My view looks like

```
                     <section>
                <%= form_tag("/applicants", method: "get") do %>
                  <%= label_tag(:applicants, "Search for:") %>
                  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
                  <br>
                  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
                <% end %>
                <br>
              </section>
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 4?, can you post the parameters log?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
   def index
     @applicants = Applicant.search(params[:q])
   end
```

Because your form has this text field:

```
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
```

Which means that the value from the text field will be sent in params[:q].

Comment: Hey so I went ahead and changed q to search (kinda the backwards of what you said, but the logic should be the same) However now I am getting a Run Time Error: Unsupported Symbol referencing the line of code <% @applicants.each do |applicant| %> when trying to print the applicants that match the search. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which query are you using? 

If you're using the  Applicant.where("first_name ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%"]) which is suggested in the comment by RUBYCASTS.IO then that may cause the issue because the ILIKE operator is specific for postgresql database.

If you're using that query and you're not using a postgres DB, try changing ILIKE to LIKE in the query.

Comment: I switched back to the  @applicants = Applicant.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name    LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]) should I follow the other suggestion?

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks it ended up being a combination of the two answers jeesh I am way off my game today! Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
@applicants = Applicant.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name    LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

to

```
@applicants = Applicant.where("first_name ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

BOOM!

If you need further live pairing help, you can check out my codementor page https://codementor.io/rubycasts/#reviews and contact me for help.

Comment: I tried this solution first by copy and paste, and got a syntax error "]" so I played around with the [ ] and got it to work, but it is still returning all the applicants. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: there shouldn't be any [ ] in the new method...... not sure what you are doing but this has worked for 5 to 6 years now so I know it works.